# change histogram x axis range

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram

I want to plot a histogram, but I have outliers in my dataset. is there a way to change the scale of my x-axis so that my histogram is more meaningful? I want the x axis range to be 0-500.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
df.column.hist(bins=150, figsize=(16, 8))
```

Comment: Set the `range` parameter: `hist(range=(0, 500), ...)`. This is effectively the same function as the matplotlib histogram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing default x range in histogram matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125880/changing-default-x-range-in-histogram-matplotlib)